# pgf plot: semi-sphere and semi-ellipsoid 3D plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am trying to plot a semi-sphere for the positive domain of z and a semi-ellipsoid for the negative domain. So far I have been able to plot each graph but as z approaches zero the plots just disappear. Here's what I have so far:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begindocument
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            axis lines=middle,
            xlabel={$x$},
            ylabel={$y$},
            zlabel={$z$},
            xmin=-3, xmax=3,
            ymin=-3, ymax=3,
            zmin=-4, zmax=3,
            xtick={-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3},
            ytick={-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3},
            ztick={-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3},
            view={170}{10},
            axis equal,
            samples=60,
            scale=3
        ]
        
       
        \addplot3[surf,opacity=0.3,shader=flat,domain=0:180,y domain=0:360]
        ({2*sin(x)*cos(y)}, {2*sin(x)*sin(y)}, {2*((cos(x))^2)^(1/2)});

        \addplot3[surf,opacity=0.3,shader=flat,domain=0:180,y domain=0:360]
        ({2*sin(x)*cos(y)}, {2*sin(x)*sin(y)}, {-3.5*((cos(x))^2)^(1/2)});
                \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code example compilable. Such cases can often be solved by using an odd value for `samples`, such as `61`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It worked great.

Comment: @JasperHabicht An answer?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the sample size in such a way that one sample happens to sit exactly on the desired position of the relevant axis. In this case, you should be able use any odd value for the `samples` option to get the desired result, for example `33` or `61`:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            axis lines=middle,
            xlabel={$x$},
            ylabel={$y$},
            zlabel={$z$},
            xmin=-3, xmax=3,
            ymin=-3, ymax=3,
            zmin=-4, zmax=3,
            xtick={-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3},
            ytick={-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3},
            ztick={-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3},
            view={170}{10},
            axis equal,
            samples=33,
            scale=3
        ]
       
            \addplot3[surf,opacity=0.3,shader=flat,domain=0:180,y domain=0:360]
            ({2*sin(x)*cos(y)}, {2*sin(x)*sin(y)}, {2*((cos(x))^2)^(1/2)});

            \addplot3[surf,opacity=0.3,shader=flat,domain=0:180,y domain=0:360]
            ({2*sin(x)*cos(y)}, {2*sin(x)*sin(y)}, {-3.5*((cos(x))^2)^(1/2)});
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]